# How to build cogl and clutter on mingw?

Tags: mingw32, clutter, cogl

I'm going to build clutter on mingw environment,  but when I try to build Cogl, there are some compling errors, unknow type: GLchar, GLintptr, GLsizeiptr.

The source code version I used is: clutter(1.8.4), cogl(1.10.2), can anybody give me some advice ?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Clutter wiki has a set of instructions for building Clutter with mingw:

http://wiki.clutter-project.org/wiki/BuildingClutterOnWindows

also, if you're using Cogl 1.10 you should use Clutter 1.10 as well.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have compiled clutter successfully on mingw after I updated the latest GL related head file from official website. Thank you for your advice :)